# How to make search from data base in laravel 5.5

Tags: laravel

public function search(Request $request){

```
    $telephone=Souscription::get ( 'q' );
    $email=Souscription::get ( 'q1' );
    if(isset($telephone) AND isset($email)){
    $fouilles = Souscription::where('telephone', 'LIKE','%'. $search.'%')->where('email', 'LIKE','%'.$search.'%')->get();  } 
    return view('rechercher', compact('souscription',compact('telephone','email')));
}
```

Comment: please provide a specific questions ,  explain and structure your code

Comment: you qestion is unclear and out of context. Nothing can be underatood unlesa you specifically explain where and what is wrong with related code

Comment: fyi, you define `$fouilles` but don't do anything with it

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

you can do something like this

```
public function search(Request $request){
        $input = $request->all();
        $telephone = $input['q'];
        $email = $input['q1'];
        $searchdb = Souscription::select(['col1','col2'])->orderBy('id','desc');

        if(isset($telephone) AND isset($email)) {
                $searchdb->where('telephone',$input['telephone']);
                $searchdb->where('email',$input['email']);
            
        } 
        $fouilles = $searchdb->get();  
        return view('rechercher', compact('souscription',compact('telephone','email', 'fouilles ')));
    }
```